# Use Renovate to update submodules in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, renovate

According to the ticket https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/pull/8164 submodules are fetched using https not ssh which should fix the issue of renovate not working for private submodules.

However, I still get the error "Error mapping git submodules during extraction"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to use HTTPS or SSH? How do you configure authentication for Renovate to access your privact submodules?

Comment: I use the global configuration with username and password (app pass). This works only with HTTPS. I do it like it is documented https://docs.renovatebot.com/modules/platform/bitbucket/

Is there a way to set it to SSH?

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, I thought it was a configuration choice whether to use https or ssh. Did you check the version of Renovate? And did you already run Renovate with debug logging on?